# looking for a good online WYSIWYG editor with RTF download capability

Tags: wysiwyg, nicedit

Does anyone know of any JavaScript/CSS scripts that offer a good WYSIWYG editor, along with the ability to download inputted information to an RTF file?

The only one I've found so far is [NicEdit](http://nicedit.com/), but I haven't been able the figure out how to convert the formatted text (which is in HTML format) to RTF and offer it for download. I've been able to store the formatted HTML in a JavaScript variable, but don't know how to proceed from there.

Do any of you know of an open source WYSIWYG text editor that offers users the ability to download their formatted text in RTF format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to go for TinyMCE. It's pretty versatile and although downloading text was not a built-in function, it was easy to set it up myself just by passing the formatted HTML text through a PHP variable once a button was pushed for download.

From there, there are various php classes that can be used to convert HTML to RTF. Just updating this in case anyone else comes up with a similar problem in the future.